# Expected value of highest die roll

Tags: probability, expected-value, geometric-distribution

Daniel will roll a fair, six-sided die until he gets a 4. What is the expected value of the highest number he
rolls through this process?

> It seems the expected number of rolls is 6. Can we reword this question to what is the expected value of the maximum of 6 die rolls?

Comment: I think we may answer this using Order Statistics for the Geometric Distribution

Comment: Intuition: Let $f(n)$ be the answer to the first problem (with ending-number $n$) and $x$ the answer to the second problem. $f(n)$ is clearly increasing. So it cannot be always equal to $m$. It remains to show whether they *can* be equal. It seems an interesting problem to calculate them exactly.

Comment: To see that the problems are different, suppose you were looking for a $1$ instead of a $4$.

Comment: To solve the original problem, note that there are only three possible answers in any given trial...$4,5$ and $6$.  If you see a $6$ before you see a $4$, you get $6$.  If you see a $5$ before you see either a $4$ or a $6$ then you get either $5$ or $6$ with equal chances (why?) and if you haven't seen any of $4,5,6$ then you have an equal chance of seeing any of those three first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

In any given trial, the answer must be $k\in \{4,5,6\}$.  Any other tosses are irrelevant.  Let $p_k$ be the probability that the result is $k$.

$p_4=\frac 13$ since you see $4,5$ or $6$ first with equal probability.

$p_6=\frac 12$ since you see $6$ before $4$ with probability $\frac 12$.

$p_5=\frac 16$ since the only sequence which results in $k=5$ is $5,4,6$.  That is to say, the only way to get $k=5$ is to see $5$ before either $4$ or $6$ and then to see a $4$ before a $6$.

Thus the answer is $$E=4\times \frac 13+5\times \frac 16 +6\times \frac 12=\frac {31}6=5.1\overline 6$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider a 2 sided fair die (sides marked 1 and 2) as a counter example. The expected number of rolls until you get a 1 (or a 2) is 2 (as this experiment is representable by a geometric random variable with parameter $p = \frac12$, so the expectation is $\frac1p = 2$).

Let $M$ be the max of 2 dice rolls.

Then $E[M] = 1*P(M=1) + 2*P(M=2) = \frac14 + 2(1-P(M=1)) = \frac14 + 2(1 - \frac14) = \frac74 \neq 2.$

Although the number of sides on this dice is different than in your example, the same reasoning can be used in the case where the number of sides is 6 to show that the suggested rewording is not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(6)$ denote the probability of getting a $(6)$ before the first $(4)$.

Let $P(5)$ denote the probability of getting a $(5)$ before the first $(4)$ and simultaneously, not getting a $(6)$ before the first $(4)$.

Then, the computation for the expected value of the highest roll is

$$4 +~ \left[ ~2 \times P(6) ~\right] ~+~ \left[ ~1 \times  ~P(5) ~\right]. \tag1 $$

---

$$P(6) = \frac{1}{6} + \left[\frac{4}{6}P(6)\right] \implies \frac{2}{6}P(6) = \frac{1}{6} \implies P(6) = \frac{1}{2}.$$

---

$$P(5) = \frac{1}{6} + \left[\frac{3}{6}P(5)\right] \implies \frac{3}{6}P(5) = \frac{1}{6} \implies P(5) = \frac{1}{3}.$$

**Thanks to lulu**, for her comment, immediately following this posting, which indicated a flaw in the above analysis, pertaining specifically to the computation of $P(5).$

$\color{red}{\text{The above analysis is wrong because:}}$

The above equation assumes that if the first roll is a $(5)$, that it is **game over**, and that the high roll will be a $(5)$.  This overlooks the fact that the die rolls do not stop, if the first roll is a $(5)$.

Instead, the die rolls continue, and by the already computed $P(6)$, (1/2) the (subsequent) time, there will be a $(6)$ before the $(4)$.

Therefore, the correct equation for $P(5)$ is

$$P(5) = \left[ ~\frac{1}{6} \times \left( ~1 - P(6) \right) ~\right] + \left[\frac{3}{6}P(5)\right] \implies $$

$$\frac{3}{6}P(5) = \left[\frac{1}{6} \times \left( ~1 - \frac{1}{2} ~\right) ~\right] \implies P(5) = \frac{1}{6}.$$

**Note**:
As indicated in the comment of lulu, an alternative (**less convoluted**) approach is to:

- Let $P(4)$ denote the probability that the high roll will be $(4)$.
- Recognize that $P(4) + P(5) + P(6) = 1$.
- Recognize that 
  $\displaystyle P(4) = \frac{1}{6} + \left[\frac{3}{6}P(4)\right] \implies \frac{3}{6}P(4) = \frac{1}{6} \implies P(4) = \frac{1}{3}.$

---

Plugging these $\color{red}{\text{now corrected}}$ results back into (1) above, the computation of expected value becomes

$$4 +~ \left[ ~2 \times \frac{1}{2} ~\right] ~+~ \left[ ~1 \times  \frac{1}{6} ~\right] = \frac{31}{6}. $$

Comment: This is not quite correct.  $P(5)$ is $\frac 16$....the only way for the result to be a $5$ is if you see a $5$ before either $4$ or $6$ and then you see a $4$ before the $6$.  Alternatively, note that $P(4)$ is clearly $\frac 13$ and $P(4)+P(5)+P(6)=1$.

Comment: @lulu +1 : Good catch, thanks.  Answer edited.  Please leave your comment **intact**.